# How can I put a figure and arrow next to a matrix?

Tags: floats, equations, matrices

I want to put a matrix besides a figure and put an arrow between them that looks as follows:

[image]

My current working is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{eeg}
    \caption{The recorded EEG signals.}
    \label{fig:eeg-signals}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation*}
    \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}   \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots   \\
        a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
    \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image]

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Put your math inside the figure. You might even want to use `tikz` to place the image on the left, the matrix in the right and draw an arrow between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show this, you can insert everything in Ti*k*Z nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (IMG) {
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
            };
        \node[below = 2mm of IMG] (LBL) {Figure 1 : eeg-signals};
        \node[right = 2cm of IMG] (MTRX) {
            $
                \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}   \\
                    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}   \\
                    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots   \\
                    a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
                \end{array}\right)
            $
            };
        \draw[line width=2pt,->] (IMG) -- (MTRX);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: with tikz]